# ORA-22922 nonexistent lob value while select

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, data-warehouse, oracle-data-integrator

I get `nonexistent lob value` during `SELECT` operation.
When I join two tables source and target I do a JOIN where `dbms_lob.compare` method is used in `JOIN` condition (to check whether the value is changed because it is dimension table, and SCD approach is used here). Also `UNION ALL` operation is used
Actually I put also `nvl(COL, empty_clob())` in case if `NULLs` are processed. But still mentioned error appears.
`NCLOB` values are used both in source and target tables.
I tried to catch those error records that cause error using `LOG ERROR INTO...` from Oracle toolbox but as the error happens in SELECT rather than in INSERT, so it doesn't help...

Also, I should mention that the query sometimes works, sometimes fails...

Comment: Did you tried with NOPARALLEL - see [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9543118700346635079)

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works... But today I replaced `nvl(COL, empty_clob())` by `nvl(COL, 'empty_clob')` and used with PARALLEL, it works... 
When I run it by hand it works, but when I run scenario in ODI (ETL tool) which generates the same SQL script, it fails with `nonexistent lob value` error

Comment: What would you recommend me to do? One idea, is to fetch error records using CURSOR so I can clarify why the mentioned error happens..